# JS conditions on images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to develop a sort of calculator which show a set of images and the client can select and depending on the choice he moves to next step of choices. At the end of all the choices he will be given a package depending on the choices of all steps chosen.

A working example of something similar can be found in this link: http://store.virginmedia.com/big-bundles.html and then clicking on the 'help me choose' popup on the left hand side.

Can anyone suggest any methods or libraries I can start from in achieving something like this ?

Comment: This is pretty straight-forward javascript. Have you tried anything yet? Are you getting stuck on something? See [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @neelsg - I am quite new to JS. I understand it and with some research I am able to code things, however I have no idea where to start from. I did some research about doing sort of checkboxes on images and save the selection but not really sure what is necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So this is pretty basic, but I created a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neelsg/jLVr2/)** just to get you started. I is not pretty, but it should give you some indication of what is required.

Here is the code, if there is something about it that is unclear, google it:

```
var selections = {
    "opt1": false,
    "opt2": false,
    "opt3": false,
    "opt4": false,
    "opt5": false,
    "opt6": false
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.option').click(function(event) {
        var id = event.target.id;
        if (selections[id]) {
            $('#' + id).removeClass('checked-option');
            selections[id] = false;
        } else {
            $('#' + id).addClass('checked-option');
            selections[id] = true;
        }
    });
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        $('#grp1').hide();
        $('#grp2').show();
    });
    $('#btn2').click(function() {
        $('#grp2').hide();
        $('#grp1').show();
    });
    $('#btn3').click(function() {
        var content = 'Selected:<ul>';
        for (var i in selections) {
            if (selections[i]) {
                content += '<li>' + i + '</li>';
            }
        }
        content += '</ul>';
        $('#grp2').hide();
        $('#done').html(content);
        $('#grp3').show();
    });
    $('#btn4').click(function() {
        $('#grp3').hide();
        $('#grp2').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Many Many Thankssss for your help!!! This is surely a great startttt !!!! Thanks so much for your help!